# My bot throws no errors, but can't seem to connect to Discord

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, discord, discord.io

My auth.json looks like this:

```
{
    "token" : "[CENSORED]"
}
```

My bot code looks like this :

```
//recognise dependancies
var auth = require("./auth.json");
var Discord = require("discord.io");
var bot = new Discord.Client({
    token: auth.token,
    autorun: true
});

//log connection message

bot.on("ready", function(){
    console.log('Logged in as ' + bot.username + ' with an ID of ' + bot.id + '')
});

...(Unrelated code)...

//reconnecting after being disconnected

bot.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log("Disconnected from Discord. Attempting to reconnect...")
    bot.connect();
})
```

Notice the disconnect function right at the end

this is what my package.json looks like :

```
{
  "name": "itachi",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "Itachi.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "Alibi",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "discord.io": "^2.5.3"
  }
}
```

When I attempt to run the itachi.js file I get no errors, but it never connects, it sends the disconnection message and then stops

```
C:\Users\[ME]\Desktop\Itachi>node itachi.js
Disconnected from Discord. Attempting to reconnect...

C:\Users\[ME]\Desktop\Itachi>
```

I don't know what to do to make it connect, I considered the possibility that it was due to slow internet, but that's not the case. I made sure that my token was correct. It just wont connect and I cant understand why.

Answer (score 0):

I found something!  I was having the exact same issue, but when I used this package instead, found on npm:

discord.io-gateway6

It worked perfectly.  Sounds like the normal package, discord.io, is just out of date, and uses old API for discord - whereas the gateway6 version